# How to remove a dmraid RAID1 member (mark as faulty)?

Tags: linux, software-raid, raid1, intel, dmraid

I have RHEL 6.8 installed on a fake Intel RAID1 (Intel Matrix). It's managed by `dmraid`, consists of sda and `sdb` and the device name is `/dev/mapper/ddf1_4c5349202020202080862682000000004711471100000a28p1`

Now I want to write something else to `sdb`. How to do that without reboot? On `mdadm`-managed arrays it's easy:

```
mdadm --fail /dev/md126 /dev/sdb
mdadm --remove /dev/md126 sdb
```